# How to Convert UTC Datetime string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Date-Time string from data like this "2019-09-02T00:00:00+02:00" and have to add for example 480 minutes to this datetime string.
How can i to this and get the result out in the same formate as string?

I have allready try this one:

```
$FromDate = "2019-09-02T00:00:00+02:00"
$FromDatetemp = Get-Date $FromDate
$FromDatetemp = $FromDatetemp.AddMinutes(480)
Write-Host $FromDatetemp
Write-Host $FromDatetemp.ToString("o")
```

but the result is in the wrong format like this: 2019-09-02T08:00:00.0000000+02:00

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell by default adds a milliseconds part to the ISO 8601 date. If you want to leve it out you need to use a custom format string. `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz`

```bsh
$FromDate = "2019-09-02T00:00:00+02:00"
$FromDatetemp = Get-Date $FromDate
$FromDatetemp = $FromDatetemp.AddMinutes(480)
Write-Host $FromDatetemp
Write-Host $FromDatetemp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I'm looking for!